# How to create a pppoe connection for wired ethernet (ieee 802.3) in android?

Tags: android, pppoe

I have an android 2.3 tablet featuring a host usb port. I also have a ethernet adapter that connects to usb.

My device supports ethernet facility as it is visible from settings menu.

Only problem is there is no way I can " create a connection"  to my ISP using login details.

I dont have a router to translate wan to lan. Neither do i have a desktop/laptop/netbook.

I am not a geek but from the little knowledge I have I figure out it is only a matter of few lines of code or an app, till now I dont seem to have found.

Answer (score 0):

It is far from trivial. Android doesn't natively support PPPoE, so you will need to build relevant code yourself, which is only doable on a rooted device. Additionally stock Android 2.3 doesn't support USB host mode. Does your tablet see the ethernet port when you connect it to USB? If so, you might have a chance. Otherwise invest in a cheap wireless router, all of them should support PPPoE.

Comment: Nikolay, Yes my tablet "sees" the ethernet port when i connect it to usb. Infact the settings> wireless n networks menu clearly specifies whether i want to configure wired ethernet. So ethernet access is without doubt. I just need a piece of code which can authenticate me to my isp. Something i happened to find in an decade old windows based smartphone. Also could u suggest some native linux commands supported in android terminal which would perform a similar function.

Comment: You phone has a driver for it, good. It is no way supported, so you need to port something like pppoe to Android and try to use it. If you are looking for a ready-made solution, this is really off topic for SO, so you should try http://android.stackexchange.com/.